# cURL keep print transfer to console?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

My application keeps print response body to console. whereas theres no function like cout or similar function that i put inside the code. Its so strange.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "libcurldll.lib");

int main() {
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html), the default behavior of libcurl is to write the response out to `stdout` using `fwrite`.

You will need to override `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` like so:

```
size_t my_write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    cout << "Received " << nmemb << " bytes" << endl;
    return nmemb;
}

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_write_callback);
```

You can control the value of `userdata` by changing [CURLOPT_WRITEDATA](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html), by default it is equal to `stdout`.

EDIT: a simple example that uses `std::string` as a memory buffer:

```
size_t my_write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata) {
    static_cast<std::string*>(userdata)->append((char*) ptr, size * nmemb);
    return nmemb;
}

std::string buf;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, my_write_callback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &buf);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
// do something with buf
```

Comment: How about i need output to string. cause i need to process directly. i don't want to save to file out output.

Comment: Updated answer. On your next question, remember to add your overall goal so people can help you better.